# Hemschech smicha

Tags: semicha

I just recently came across the concept of hemschech smicha (https://torahdownloads.com/shiur-1010280.html). Does anyone know the origin of this concept?

Comment: Did you see this concept in the same vein as "סמיכה לדורות"?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, user419691. Remember that you can make your Stack Exchange account more personalized by editing your profile and customizing a username for yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. (And I recommend our [tour].) "Can anyone offer sources on this concept?" Do you seek sources *for* the concept, i.e. sources that say such a concept exists at all? If not, then you seek sources on (i.e. related to) the concept — but that's too broad a question for the Stack Exchange format, I'm afraid.

Comment: Or "shlichusaihu ka'avdinan", perhaps.

Comment: Can you let us know where you heard about this?

Comment: Where i heard it: https://torahdownloads.com/shiur-1010280.html. I'm embarrassed that I've never come across it before yet I've talked to people i consider pretty knowledgeable who have never heard of it either.

Comment: So you *are* asking for more sources that discuss this concept? If so, then I’m going to have to agree with @msh210 that this is too broad.

Comment: Asking for a text source or sources is considered too broad? Can you explain?

Comment: @user419691 Asking for the source, or even parameters, of a concept is one thing. Asking for all the sources that discuss it is something else. Which are you asking? As it stands, I’m just confused what your intent is.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Can we take it out of [on hold] status ? Or is there another edit y'all consider necessary?